# Use Software Updater or Software for updates? Or both?

Tags: updates, software-center, update-manager

So this is puzzling. I'm running 16.04.1 (upgraded in place from 14.04) and not certain of procedure for regular updates.

I get notifications from Software Updater, as with prior versions, and run those. But when I launch the new Software (replacement for Software Center) I also see updates to be installed from that application.

I'm doing both, but am unsure what is happening here. Anyone know what's going on?

Here are results of command line updating:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [95.7 kB]   
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [94.5 kB]    
Ign:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb stable InRelease               
Hit:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Hit:7 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Hit:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb stable Release                 
Hit:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease          
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [364 kB]
Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages [359 kB]
Get:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [314 kB]
Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages [310 kB]
Fetched 1,537 kB in 2s (722 kB/s)                          
Reading package lists... Done

$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: What does this command output - `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade` ?

Comment: And also please add the output of `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: issue those sudo commands from terminal which you open by typing  ctrl-alt-T ...  to answer your question both are showing you the same updates

Comment: Thanks; output above. Software Updater did one thing, and immediately running Software and applying updates did different things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an either or option.  Use whatever tool works for you.  I use aptitude, apt-get, and Software Updater on some systems.

These are mostly different front-ends in front of the same data.  `aptitude` uses `apt-get` among other tools.  I haven't bothered to discover which tools Software Updater uses, but I expect `apt-get` will be one of them.